# Why dd is not working?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, dd

I have an SD that is giving me a lot of problems. Data started to get corrupted, specially pictures and now I am trying to wipe it and give it another use.

I am still able to see the pictures that were not corrupted... the problem is that I have already tried formating it via GParted, and even ran a:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Getting the following output:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/mmcblk0': No space left on device
60304+0 records in
60303+0 records out
63232278528 bytes (63 GB, 59 GiB) copied, 1973,66 s, 32,0 MB/s
```

But I am still able to see the folders and images in the SD.

What can be the cause for this problem? And, how can I solve it?

I am guessing it should be pausible by the fact that data can still be accessed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The cause is hardware failure. Use another card.

Comment: Make sure the SD card isn't mounted when you run `dd`